# Django beginners issue issues 

Tags: python, django, apache

I am new to web development just pieced together my first django web app and integrated with apache using mod_wsgi.
the app has some 15 parameters on which you could query multiple SQL server databases and the result can be downloaded as .xls file; have deployed the same on the company network.

the problem is when i access the web app on one machine and set query parameters, the same parameters get set in the web app when i try opening it from a different machine (web client) .
Its like there is just one global object which is being served to all the web client.

Am using django template tags to set values in the app's html pages.

not using any models in the django project as am querying SQL server DB which are already built.

the query function from my views.py looks like

```
def query(self,request):
    """
    """
    print "\n\n\t inside QUERY PAGE:",request.method,"\n\n"

    self.SummaryOfResults_list = []
    if self.vmd_cursor != -1:
        self.vmd_cursor.close()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        QueryPage_post_dic = request.POST
        print "\n\nQueryPage_post_dic   :",QueryPage_post_dic

        self.err_list = []
        self.err_list = db_qry.validate_entry(QueryPage_post_dic)

        if len(self.err_list):
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/error/')
        else:
            channel_numbers,JPEG_Over_HTTP,Codec,format,rate_ctrl,transport,img_sz,BuildInfo_versions, self.numspinner_values_dic = db_qry.process_postdata(QueryPage_post_dic, self.numspinner_values_dic)


            return self.get_result(request,channel_numbers,JPEG_Over_HTTP,Codec,format,rate_ctrl,transport,img_sz,BuildInfo_versions)

    else:
        print "\nself.Cam_Selected_list inside qry  :",self.Cam_Selected_list
        if (len(self.Cam_Selected_list) != 1):
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/error/')

        self.tc_dic,self.chnl_dic,self.enbl_dic,self.frmt_dic,self.cdectyp_dic,self.imgsz_dic,self.rtctrl_dic,self.jpg_ovr_http_dic,self.trnsprt_dic,self.cdec_dic,self.typ_dic,self.resolution_dic, self.vmd_cursor = populate_tbls.Read_RefTbls(self.Cam_Selected_list[0])



        c = self.get_the_choices(self.Cam_Selected_list[0])
        c['camera_type']= self.Cam_Selected_list[0]

        for k,v in self.numspinner_values_dic.items():
            c[k] = v

        self.vmd_cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT [GD Build Info] FROM MAIN")
        res_versions = self.vmd_cursor.fetchall()
        version_list = []
        ver_list = ['',' ']
        for version in res_versions:
            tmp_ver = version[0].encode()
            if (tmp_ver not in ver_list):
                version_list.append(tmp_ver)
        c['build_info'] = version_list
        print "\n\n c dic   :",c
        c.update(csrf(request))
        return render_to_response('DBQuery.html',c)
```

and the dictionary being passed to render_to_response holds the values that setting checkboxes and multiselect boxes (dojo)

thanks

Comment: You're going to have to show us some code.

Comment: sounds like you are maybe saving the search parameters as objects, did you set the search up as a Model? What you should be doing is creating Models to fit your existing databases and then use a Form to send request parameters via GET or POST. Can you post some code? The appropriate view from `views.py` may be the most helpful initially

Comment: also, this seems to not have anything to do with Apache at all. You should probably consider editing the title and tags.

Answer (score 2):

> Its like there is just one global object which is being served to all the web client.

What you're saying is probably exactly what's happening. Unless you're building whatever object that `self` in that example code is anew for each request, it will be practically randomly shared between clients.

Comment: i am creating the object in the urls.py...... any thoughts about where its needed to create the object to have one object per client.

Comment: Create it per request, in the view function, or use some other way of making it request-local. (You could use a Django middleware to assign it as an attribute for the `request`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can store your global variable in SQL DB that you are using. This way you can retain the value/state of the variable across request -> response cycle.

If you need faster response time explore Key->Value Pair in memory datastore like redis.

To add to what's mentioned by AKX I suggest that you read up on HTTP Request -> HTTP Response cycle and How web applications work.